# How to put poster for embedded youtube using iframe

Tags: youtube

I want to have a poster image for a youtube video.

So when you click an image, you will autoplay youtube video.

But since I want to remove controller I have to use iframe

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/q6EoRBvdVPQ?rel=0&amp;controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Something like this.

And I have several videos to apply, so I wonder how the code including iframe should be.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you can apply this [solution](https://gist.github.com/zigotica/4438876) I Tried it is working fine

the main idea is you just display you custom poster as following and include the embed as commented code

```
<div class="video">
    <img src="poster.jpg">
    <!-- <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/q6EoRBvdVPQ?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
</div>
```

when user click on the image embed of the youtube video injected instead of the image as following

```
$(function() { 
    var videos  = $(".video");

        videos.on("click", function(){
            var elm = $(this),
                conts   = elm.contents(),
                le      = conts.length,
                ifr     = null;

            for(var i = 0; i<le; i++){
              if(conts[i].nodeType == 8) ifr = conts[i].textContent;
            }

            elm.addClass("player").html(ifr);
            elm.off("click");
        });
});
```

which is better for performance because embeds won't be loaded until user click it