# Why youtube video wont load

Tags: javascript, html

I tried loading a youtube video on my website but when I click the play button it takes roughly 23 seconds of black screen before the page pops `It may have been moved or deleted.` message.

I tried it with multiple videos, uploaded by myself or others but same error.

this is the code I have done for it.

```
<!-- Video Section -->
<section id="video" class="video-section">
  <div class="tf-bg-overlay">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="video-intro">
         <a class="popup-video" href="https://youtu.be/8hTSK1iDcvQ"> <i class="fa fa-play"></i>  </a>
         <h2>Video Introducing</h2><p>(coming soon)</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!--/.container-->
  </div>
  <!--/.overlay-->
</section>
<!-- /.Video Section -->
```

This is the css for the video section

```
.video-introducing{
    background: url(../images/video-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 390px;
    border: 5px solid #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 1px #eee;
}
```

javascript for the popup.
      $(function() { 
        var videos  = $(".video");

```
        videos.on("click", function(){
            var elm = $(this),
                conts   = elm.contents(),
                le      = conts.length,
                ifr     = null;

            for(var i = 0; i<le; i++){
              if(conts[i].nodeType == 8) ifr = conts[i].textContent;
            }

            elm.addClass("player").html(ifr);
            elm.off("click");
        });
});
```

EDIT: I made some changes to the initial code and added javascript code to make a popup for the video.

Comment: Try using this link instead and tell me what happens? `https://youtu.be/8hTSK1iDcvQ` [This is the `share` youtube link instead of the straight url]

Comment: @EGC shows ``youtube.com refused to connect``

Comment: Okay.. so what are you trying to achieve? Is using the `Youtube` generated `embed` code not an option? This is the `Youtube embed` code which should replace everything within the `video-intro` div: `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8hTSK1iDcvQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: ok this actually does load the video. which is really awesome. But how do I hide the video thumnail whic looks like this ``https://prnt.sc/pti5j9`` and have it shown like this: ``https://prnt.sc/pti5p7`` but when I click the play button it to be open in a popup and play? I know this is not what the question asks above but this is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Not strictly possible, you'll have to have a placeholder image and when the user clicks you'll have to inject the iframe using JS or JQuery. The solution for what you're asking is here [How to put poster for embedded youtube using iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51448434/11700321)

Comment: added the javascript code Ahmed has suggested in the page you linked. It opens it as a popup but youtube refuses to connect.

Comment: Hey, update the code in your question to include these changes and we will attempt to get you some sort of working solution

Comment: Already updated it. Maybe I should create an entire ``<div></div>`` pannel and hide it but show it when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the w3schools website https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp what you want is an iframe so you can view content from another web page on your site and you need to add **embed** in the url

Here's the example they provide on their website:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it actually works, but in the question comment section I asked something to EGC who gave me a similar code to yours. Can you please check it out and see if you got an answer for that please?

Comment: I think the link EGC posted is what you are after. Like he and the post says you'll want to paste your image in and then use some javascript/jquery to handle loading the iframe. If you are new to jquery then take a look at the official site https://jquery.com/ and perhaps check out some youtube vids to get you started. Sorry for not supplying a concrete coded answer